# Complexity of bin packing with defined function of bin weight

Tags: theory, computation-theory, number-theory

I'm struggling with the following problem:

Given `n` integers, place them into `m` bins, so that the total sum in all bins is minimized. The trick is that once numbers are placed in the bin, the total weight/cost/sum of the bin is computed in non-standard way:

`weight_of_bin = Sigma - k * X` Where `Sigma` is a sum of integers in the bin
`k` is the number of integers in the bin
`X` is the number of prime divisors that integers located in the bin have in common.

In other words, by grouping together the numbers that have many prime divisors in common, and by placing different quantities of numbers in different bins, we can achieve some "savings" in the total sum.

I use bin-packing formulation because I suspect the problem to be NPhard but I have trouble finding a proof.  I am not a number theory person and am confused with the fact that weight of the bin depends on the items that are in the bin.

Are there hardness results for this type of problem?

P.S. I only know that the numbers are integers. There is no explicit limit on the largest integer involved in the problem.

Thanks for any pointers you can give.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but hopefully it gives you some things to think about.

First, by way of clarification: what do you know about the prime divisors of the integers? Finding all the prime divisors of the integers in the input to the problem is difficult enough as it is. Factorization isn't known to be NP-complete, but it also isn't known to be in P. If you don't already know the factorization of the inputs, that might be enough to make this problem "hard".

In general, I expect this problem will be at least as hard as bin packing. A simple argument to show this is that it is possible that none of the integers given have any common prime divisors (for example, if you are given a set of distinct primes). In which case, the problem reduces to standard bin packing since the weight of the bin is just the standard weight. If you have a guarantee about how many common divisors there may be, you may possibly do better, but probably not in general.

There is a variant of bin packing, called [VM packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) (based on the idea of packing virtual machines based on memory requirements) where objects are allowed to share space (such as shared virtual memory pages). Your objective function, where you subtract a term based on "shared" prime divisors reminds me of that. Even in the case of VM packing, the problem is NP-hard. If the sharing has a nice hierarchy, good approximation algorithms exist, but they are still only approximations.